# How to compare posted webapp2 value to string in a form using %{name}s python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, webapp2

I'm a python newbie using wepapp2 as a standalone with python 2.7.5 and Mssql server express 2012.

For now, I'm trying to build a simple webpage for myself without a frame work. It's a form imported into a form handler. The handler uses string formatting to persist the form values when a required field is missing, but I'm having issues retaining values for select elements.

Debugging showed me that val type is 'str' and when outputted to HTML using %(status)r', the value was u'o', but the length of val equaled 10. I assume this is the reason why val == 'o' is false, but why? How may I get the conditional statements below to result True? Thanks.

formhandler.py

```
class TaskFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
      ...
      col = self.request.get(field)
      ...
      if error_flag:
        self.write_display(error_flag,fields[0],...)

    def write_display(self,error='',status='',...):
       form_vals = {'error':error,'status':status,...}
       self.response.write(webview.form % form_vals)
```

webview.py

```
from string import Template

    val = '%(status)s'
    if val == 'o':
        params = dict(op1=' selected',op2='',op3='')
    elif val == 'c':
        params = dict(op1='',op2=' selected',op3='')
    elif val == 'a':
        params = dict(op1='',op2='',op3=' selected')
    else:
        params = dict(op1='',op2=' selected',op3=len(val))

    template = Template("""
        <label>Temp_Status
            <select name='status'>
                <option value='o'${op1}>Opened</option>
                <option value='c'${op2}>Completed</option>
                <option value='a'${op3}>Aged</option>
            </select>
        </label><br><br>
        """)

    form = """
<form method='post' action='/tasksystem/taskform'>
...
...
""" + template.substitute(params) + """
...
...
</form>
"""
```

This is the output from the webpage's page source:

```
<label>Temp_Status
        <select name='status'>
            <option value='o'>Opened</option>
            <option value='c' selected>Completed</option>
            <option value='a'10>Aged</option>
        </select>
    </label><br><br>
```

Comment: I dont know webapp2, but 10 is the length of %(status)s. Correct would be val = str(status) as the 1st line, I think.

Comment: I guess I'm not setup to receive notifications. Your reply would have saved some frustration. However, it goes to show that when you don't understand something fully, the obvious is overlooked. Thing is, I still don't understand it. My new solution works, but It would seem that the old one should have too. I'll post the change once I figure out how too, tx.

Comment: Such errors are annoying, but it happens to the best :) Can you please accept my answer, I finally made it an answer. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know webapp2, but 10 is the length of `%(status)s`. Correct would be `val = str(status)` as the 1st line, I think. Or simply check for `status == XX`

Answer (score 0):

After posting this new solution and comparing it to the old, I now believe the old
did not work because '%(status)s' was never used within the context of a string of text for substitution. As @Hendrik pointed out, it was literally being used as the string itself and failing because 'o'=='%(status)s' is false.

This explains why I saw the value in the webpage source with op1='%(status)s', because params was concatenated into the form text and rendered by the template class. Unbelievable! I hope this posting helps those looking for a pure python solution in retaining HTML SELECT element values without a framework. tx

formhandler.py

```
class TaskFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    ...
    def write_display(self,error='',status='',...):
       if status == 'o':
            op1,op2,op3 = ' selected','',''
       elif status == 'c':
            op1,op2,op3 = '',' selected',''
       elif status == 'a':
            op1,op2,op3 = '','',' selected'
       else:
            op1,op2,op3 = '','','selected'
       form_vals = {'error':error,'status':status,'op1':op1,...}
       self.response.write(webview.form % form_vals)
```

webview.py

```
from string import Template

    params = dict(op1='%(op1)s',op2='%(op2)s',op3='%(op3)s')
    template = Template("""
        <label>Temp_Status
            <select name='status'>
                <option value='o'${op1}>Opened</option>
                <option value='c'${op2}>Completed</option>
                <option value='a'${op3}>Aged</option>
            </select>
        </label><br><br>
        """)

    form = """
<form method='post' action='/tasksystem/taskform'>
...
""" + template.substitute(params) + """
...
</form>
"""
```